# How to adjusting string length

Tags: php, string

I am trying to limit the characters of a string. Additionally, if the string is less than the required characters, I want to add padding to it.

```
function create_string($string, $length) {
    $str_len = strlen($string);
    if($str_len > $length) {
        //if string is greater than max length, then strip it
        $str = substr($string, 0, $length);
    } else {
        //if string is less than the required length, pad it with what it needs to be the length
        $remaining = $length-$str_len;
        $str = str_pad($string, $remaining);
    }

    return $str;
}
```

My input is

> "Nik's Auto Salon"

which is 16 characters. The second parameter is `40`.

However, This string is returned

```
"Nik's Auto Salon        "
```

which has only eight characters of padding added onto it. That doesn't seem right.

I also tried this string:

> Gold Package Mobile Car Detail

With this input, it returns a string with NO padding added onto it. When that phrase is shorter than the required 45 length I put in the second parameter place.

How can I make this function work according to my specifications?

Comment: Doesnt the strlen return an string?  So your trying to deduct  an int from an string. That might be the problem?

Comment: `strlen` returns an `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str_pad` doesn't add spaces equal to its second parameter, it pads the string TO the length given in the second parameter. This isn't very clear even in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php).

Try this instead (and take out the line where you calculate `$remaining`):

```
$str = str_pad($string, $length);
```

Comment: Ah that is correct. However str_pad doesn't bump it down to two lines if it becomes two lines? The reason I'm doing this is because I'm spitting out a title and I want it to take up two lines if it's a short character or strip it down so it's only two lines. Since I want everything uniform.

Comment: `str_pad` has no way of knowing what your desired line length is. it simply adds spaces up to the length you give it; it doesn't insert newlines. if you want to add newlines, you'll have to add them yourself somehow.

Comment: you could easily add a newline wherever you want in the string, though. if you can't figure out how to do it, ask another question. :)